# Set the first value of the select tag as default

Tags: angular, typescript, select, components

I use reusable component `<my-type>`in a form. I need to set the ''--select--'' option as default value.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="items?.length">
  <select [ngModel]="selectedIndex" (ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="null" selected>--Select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">
      {{ item.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</ng-container>
```

i used

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.selectIndex.setValue(this.items?.[0]?.name);
}
```

It works. But when i post data from the form, the value is always 0.

`selected`, is not working. so how to fix that?

Comment: What does the "selectIndex"? Where is it binded?

Comment: something is wrong, you are using `[ngModel]="selectedIndex"` which means you are using template driven, but then you do `this.selectIndex.setValue(this.items?.[0]?.name);` which makes me feel it's a `FormControl` which is reactive form, we need the full component class code not just the `ngOnInit`